# Vigor2925 keeps dropping connectivity

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

For the past few days our router has been dropping all connectivity, mean computers lose connection to the Internet, and to the router itself I believe (we also have a switch in place).

The setup is as follows:

- Various PCs connected to the switch
- Switch plugged into Router (Vigor2925)
- Second cheapo router connected to Vigor (acts as a WiFi bridge)
- Vigor setup for two VLANs, one for the PCs, one for the WiFi bridge router
- Bonded pair Internet connection into Vigor Router

I've powered cycled the lot, and still seeing cut-outs.

They only last a few seconds, but happen frequently.

[Link to a log file from the Vigor router here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rujccv6uq15aerm/004_2015-10-14_11-34-23.log?dl=0)

In the log file, there are entries like this (note how the date goes from Oct 14 to Jan 1)

```
<150>Oct 14 11:37:31 Vigor: Local User (MAC=8C-89-A5-C1-4C-7E): 192.168.1.19:57823 -> 216.58.208.40:443 (UDP)
<150>Oct 14 11:37:31 Vigor: Local User (MAC=8C-89-A5-C1-4C-7E): 192.168.1.19:38444 -> 23.21.49.236:443 (TCP) 
<150>Oct 14 11:37:31 Vigor: Local User (MAC=8C-89-A5-C1-4C-7E): 192.168.1.19:38445 -> 23.21.49.236:443 (TCP) 
<150>Oct 14 11:37:31 Vigor: Local User (MAC=8C-89-A5-C1-4C-7E): 192.168.1.19:38446 -> 104.16.12.8:443 (TCP) 
<150>Oct 14 11:37:31 Vigor: Local User (MAC=8C-89-A5-C1-4C-7E): 192.168.1.19:38447 -> 54.88.71.191:443 (TCP) 
<150>Oct 14 11:37:31 Vigor: Local User (MAC=8C-89-A5-C1-4C-7E): 192.168.1.19:38448 -> 54.88.71.191:443 (TCP) 
<150>Oct 14 11:37:31 Vigor: Local User (MAC=8C-89-A5-C1-4C-7E): 192.168.1.19:38449 -> 198.41.209.121:443 (TCP) 
<150>Oct 14 11:37:31 Vigor: Local User (MAC=90-2B-34-51-F1-12): 192.168.1.17:51114 -> 64.233.166.188:5228 (TCP) 
<150>Oct 14 11:37:31 Vigor: [WLAN] AUTH - MBSS(0), Rcv AUTH seq#1, Alg=0, Status=0 from [wcid=255]c0:ee:fb:24:22:b0

<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: Local User (MAC=BC-AE-C5-43-AA-17): 192.168.1.18:51332 -> 216.58.209.229:443 (UDP)
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: [WLAN] AUTH - Class 2 error, Send DEAUTH frame to 04:e6:76:5a:d8:1f

<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - MLME Associate MAC c0:ee:fb:24:22:b0

<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - WPA2 capable client
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - MLME Associate MAC ec:35:86:3d:66:9e

<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - WPA2 capable client
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - WPA handshake start for c0:ee:fb:24:22:b0
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - RSN, Send key to: c0:ee:fb:24:22:b0
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - send 1st packet in 4-way handshake
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - WPA handshake start for ec:35:86:3d:66:9e
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - RSN, Send key to: ec:35:86:3d:66:9e
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - send 1st packet in 4-way handshake
<181>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: [DHCP] Vigor DHCP server has given out an IP [MAC: c0-ee-fb-24-22-b0, IP: 192.168.1.15]
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - EAPoL_handler, from ec:35:86:3d:66:9e
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - Wpa_EAPoL_handler, from ec:35:86:3d:66:9e
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - EAPOL_KEY
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - parse_EAPOL_Key
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - Rx message 2 in 4-way handshake
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - RSN, Send key to: ec:35:86:3d:66:9e
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - send 3rd packet in 4-way handshake
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - EAPoL_handler, from c0:ee:fb:24:22:b0
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - Wpa_EAPoL_handler, from c0:ee:fb:24:22:b0
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - EAPOL_KEY
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - parse_EAPOL_Key
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - Rx message 2 in 4-way handshake
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - RSN, Send key to: c0:ee:fb:24:22:b0
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - send 3rd packet in 4-way handshake
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - EAPoL_handler, from ec:35:86:3d:66:9e
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - Wpa_EAPoL_handler, from ec:35:86:3d:66:9e
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - EAPOL_KEY
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - parse_EAPOL_Key
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - Rx message 4 in 4-way handshake
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - WPA handshake finish for ec:35:86:3d:66:9e
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - EAPoL_handler, from c0:ee:fb:24:22:b0
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - Wpa_EAPoL_handler, from c0:ee:fb:24:22:b0
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - EAPOL_KEY
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - parse_EAPOL_Key
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - Rx message 4 in 4-way handshake
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - WPA handshake finish for c0:ee:fb:24:22:b0
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: Local User (MAC=C0-EE-FB-24-22-B0): 192.168.1.15:57744 -> 184.173.161.174:5222 (TCP) 
<134>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: [ARP][LAN IP conflict - lan ip conflicts with the one host whose MAC is C4:6E:1F:BF:25:3A, please contact with the administrator]
<150>Jan  1 00:00:03 Vigor: Local User (MAC=D0-E1-40-8A-DE-BA): 192.168.2.13:64161 -> 17.110.224.74:5223 (TCP) 
<134>Jan  1 00:00:04 Vigor: [ARP][LAN IP conflict - lan ip conflicts with the one host whose MAC is C4:6E:1F:BF:25:3A, please contact with the administrator]
<181>Jan  1 00:00:04 Vigor: [DHCP] Vigor DHCP server has given out an IP [MAC: ec-35-86-3d-66-9e, IP: 192.168.1.28]
<150>Jan  1 00:00:04 Vigor: Local User (MAC=10-DD-B1-BD-7F-63): 192.168.1.23:28756 -> 52.1.1.135:3000 (UDP)
<150>Jan  1 00:00:04 Vigor: Local User (MAC=10-DD-B1-BD-7F-63): 192.168.1.23:61823 -> 52.0.104.40:3000 (TCP) 
<150>Jan  1 00:00:04 Vigor: Local User (MAC=10-DD-B1-BD-7F-63): 192.168.1.23:28756 -> 52.0.104.40:3000 (UDP)
<150>Jan  1 00:00:04 Vigor: Local User (MAC=10-DD-B1-BD-7F-63): 192.168.1.23:61824 -> 52.0.102.230:3000 (TCP) 
<150>Jan  1 00:00:04 Vigor: Local User (MAC=10-DD-B1-BD-7F-63): 192.168.1.23:28756 -> 52.0.102.230:3000 (UDP)
<150>Jan  1 00:00:04 Vigor: Local User (MAC=08-60-6E-88-B1-A2): 192.168.1.22:59805 -> 216.58.210.69:443 (UDP)
<150>Jan  1 00:00:04 Vigor: Local User (MAC=10-DD-B1-BD-7F-63): 192.168.1.23:61825 -> 52.1.1.135:3000 (TCP) 
<150>Jan  1 00:00:04 Vigor: Local User (MAC=10-DD-B1-BD-7F-63): 192.168.1.23:61826 -> 52.0.102.230:3000 (TCP) 
<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: Local User (MAC=10-DD-B1-BD-7F-63): 192.168.1.23:61821 -> 52.1.40.103:3000 (TCP) 
<134>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: [ARP][LAN IP conflict - lan ip conflicts with the one host whose MAC is C4:6E:1F:BF:25:3A, please contact with the administrator]
<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: [WLAN] AUTH - MBSS(0), Rcv AUTH seq#1, Alg=0, Status=0 from [wcid=255]4c:60:de:6f:5c:fb

<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: [WLAN] AUTH_RSP - Send AUTH response (SUCCESS)...

<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: [WLAN] ASSOC - MBSS(0), receive ASSOC request from 4c:60:de:6f:5c:fb

<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: [WLAN] ASSOC - Send ASSOC response (Status=0)...

<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - MLME Associate MAC 4c:60:de:6f:5c:fb

<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - MLME Associate MAC 78:31:c1:be:1f:ac

<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - WPA2 capable client
<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - WPA handshake start for 78:31:c1:be:1f:ac
<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - RSN, Send key to: 78:31:c1:be:1f:ac
<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - send 1st packet in 4-way handshake
<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - EAPoL_handler, from 78:31:c1:be:1f:ac
<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - Wpa_EAPoL_handler, from 78:31:c1:be:1f:ac
<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - EAPOL_KEY
<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - parse_EAPOL_Key
<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - Rx message 2 in 4-way handshake
<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - RSN, Send key to: 78:31:c1:be:1f:ac
<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - send 3rd packet in 4-way handshake
<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - EAPoL_handler, from 78:31:c1:be:1f:ac
<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - Wpa_EAPoL_handler, from 78:31:c1:be:1f:ac
<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - EAPOL_KEY
<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - parse_EAPOL_Key
<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - Rx message 4 in 4-way handshake
<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: WLAN_DBG - WPA handshake finish for 78:31:c1:be:1f:ac
<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: [WLAN] WPA: send Msg1 of 4-way

<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: [WLAN] Receive EAPoL-Key frame from STA 4C-60-DE-6F-5C-FB

<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: [WLAN] WPA: recieve Msg2 of 4-way (4C-60-DE-6F-5C-FB)

<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: [WLAN] WPA: send Msg3 of 4-way

<181>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: [DHCP] Vigor DHCP server has given out an IP [MAC: 4c-60-de-6f-5c-fb, IP: 192.168.1.59]
<166>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: [DHCPv6s] Received solicit from FE80::F13E:1A54:334C:B475 on LAN1
<166>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: [DHCPv6] Elapsed time: 0
<166>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: [DHCPv6] Client DUID: 00:01:00:01:1b:f5:04:29:c0:4a:00:02:1f:ab
<166>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: [DHCPv6] IA_NA: ID=237036842, T1=0, T2=0
<166>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: [DHCPv6] Requested option: domain search list
<166>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: [DHCPv6] Requested option: DNS
<166>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: [DHCPv6] Requested option: vendor specific info
<166>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: [DHCPv6] Requested option: client FQDN
<150>Jan  1 00:00:05 Vigor: [WLAN] Receive EAPoL-Key frame from STA 4C-60-DE-6F-5C-FB
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the logfile. I'm not going to download some random file from dropbox.

Comment: Have you talked to your ISP? Maybe they are having issues with your connnection.

Comment: The log file contains about 10k lines. However, I will add some bits that look suspicious

Comment: @MrPablo Its normal for the date to change like that on bootup, time resets then it grabs the right time from the ISPs timeserver when the WAN is brought up. But logs arent showing any reboots or relinks.

Comment: That makes sense about the date then. So what could cause the router to keep dropping out? There isn't a ton of devices connected in total, and it is designed to easily handle our infrastructure.